# Update with calculated Value from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

orders

```
payout_id  subtotal  p_p
------------------------
1          10        2
1          11        3
2          15        NULL
3          20        5
```

payout (before update)

```
payout_id   income
------------------
1                              
2            
3
```

payout (what I'm looking for after update)

```
payout_id  income
-----------------
1          26                  
2          15
3          25
```

This is my code:

```
UPDATE payout
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  payout_id, SUM(subtotal + IFNULL(p_p, 0)) AS payout_total
FROM    orders
GROUP BY payout_id
) temp ON payout.payout_id = temp.payout_id
SET payout.income = temp.payout_total
WHERE   payout.payout_id = temp.payout_id;
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
> update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable
> safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and
> reconnect.

This is confusing to me, as payout_id is my primary key for the payout table - or am I misunderstanding the error?

If I change my where clause to: WHERE payout.payout_id = '1'; it will add 26 into payout table for ID 1, so I think my code is pretty much there, I just don't understand how to update it for all IDs.

To add - payout table rows are already created, I just want to update the rows to add in the calculated values.

Comment: I suspect it's because your `WHERE` condition is the same as the `ON` condition, so it's removing it before doing the safety check.

Comment: This seems like a bug in MySQL.

Comment: The workaround is to disable safe mode while doing this query.

Comment: @barmar I've read about disabling the safe mode, but was cautious to do so if my code was wrong anyway. I will disable and test it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like here:

```sql
UPDATE payout p
SET p.INCOME = (  SELECT  Sum(SUBTOTAL + IFNULL(P_P, 0)) AS TOTAL
                  FROM    orders
                  WHERE   PAYOUT_ID = p.PAYOUT_ID
                  GROUP   BY PAYOUT_ID
              );
```

... see it in detail at --> https://dbfiddle.uk/LMxuWteP

OR - just without WHERE clause since the tables are inner joined by ON clause:

```sql
UPDATE payout as p
  INNER JOIN (    SELECT  PAYOUT_ID, Sum(SUBTOTAL + IFNULL(P_P, 0)) AS TOTAL
                  FROM    orders
                  GROUP   BY PAYOUT_ID
            ) as o ON o.PAYOUT_ID = p.PAYOUT_ID 
SET p.INCOME = o.TOTAL;
```

Where could be used to filter rows to be updated either like you did it putting id = 1 or, to prevent updating rows with the same values like :

```sql
WHERE p.INCOME != o.TOTAL;
```

... see it at --> https://dbfiddle.uk/CQsV88Il